# My in my header file DNode is not being recognized as a data type

Tags: c++, class, templates, header-files

I declared a node class in my main.cpp but when I try to use the node when declaring functions in my header file it does not recognize the node data type.

```
template<class E> class doublyLinkedList;  
class doublyLinkedList  
{
        public:
        doublyLinkedList();
        ~doublyLinkedList();
        bool IsEmpty() const;
        const T& front() const; // return front node
        const T& back() const; //returning rear node
        void addToFront(const T& e); // add to front
        void addToBack(const T& e); //adds to end
        void removeFront(); // remove front node
        void removeBack(); //remove rear node
private:
        DNode<T>* header; // sentinel node front of node
        DNode<T>* trailer; //sentinel node for back of node
protected:
        void add(DNode* v, const Element& e); // insert new node before v
        void remove(DNode* v); // remove node v
  };  

 template<class E> class doublyLinkedList; //forward declaration    

template <class E>  
 class DNode{
private:
        E element;      //node's actual value
        DNode<E>* head;
        DNode<E>* tail;
        template<class T> friend class doublyLinkedList;
     };
```

Comment: hmm..you dont declare classes in .cpp file . you do that in the header.

Comment: i think your problem is that your class is perhaps declared after the main function hence main cannot find it. best to add your main.cpp in your question

Comment: You declare stuff in headers. You implement stuff in the cpp file. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule is helpful to your troubles.

Comment: ![main](https://imgur.com/a/XyhQIzI)
![header](https://imgur.com/a/4btM5V3)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there not in a comment. The code should be text not a link and not an image.

Comment: @JefferyA  i looked at the code you screen captured. you forward declaring  DoublyLinkedList after including the header (#include "DoublyLinklist") in your main.cpp. remove the forward declaration

Comment: also you have to make sure that your DNode class declaration is on top of class declaration of the DoublyLinkedList. or you have to forward declare it. this is why keeping each class within their own header and .cpp files is less annoying.

Comment: and.. after removing forward declaration of DoublyLinkedList, move your DoublyLinkedList constructor definition into  DoublyLinkedList.cpp from main.cpp

Answer (score 1):

Typically, classes will be declared in header files to prevent the very problem that you are seeing.  Nothing prevents a class/struct being declared locally in a body file (cpp) file however.

If you would like a class to be visible to another class then it must be either fully declared or forward declared.

```
class foo; // forward declaration

class bar {
    bar(foo& r):ref(r){};
    foo & ref; // Ok because of the forward declaration
    foo* ptr;  // Ok 
    //foo full;  // Not legal as the full declaration is needed. 

};

class foo{ // declaration of class
// members and methods
};

class third{
   bar b; // Ok, full declaration is available;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose your class is `MyNode`, your function is `MyFunc(MyNode)`, the header file is `foo.h`, and you have a source file `bar.cpp`. (This is one reason you should give examples in your questions; if you don't, then other people get to name your things.)

Naturally `bar.cpp` contains this line:

```
#include "foo.h"
```

When the compiler tries to compile `bar.cpp`, it encounters the declaration `MyFunc(MyNode X)`, and complains *"what the heck is a `MyNode`? I quit!"*

The simplest way to solve this is to put the definition of `MyNode` in `foo.h`, above the declaration of the function that uses it.

The best way is to put a line in `foo.c`:

```
class MyNode;
```

above any other mention of `MyNode`. (This tells the compiler "there's a class named `MyNode`, don't worry what it is, it will be provided later.) And somehow (e.g. with an `#include` statement) put the the definition of `MyNode` above any code that actually uses it.